# Resizing Partition?

Tags: linux, partition

I've got an unused partition that I want to use to resize my working partition.

I can delete the unused partition, but am unable to expand my working partition because the EFI partition is in the way. Here's a screenshot on my /dev/sda:
[image: Partition Table]

How do I get around this, please?

Answer (score 2):

Move the EFI partition (`sda2`) to the beginning of the disk then move `sda3`, expand `sda3`, and finally expand `sda5`.

Comment: Good, concise description. Note that these moves and resizes will change UUIDs, so you'll have to change the /etc/fstab (if it uses UUIDs, which it hopefully does), the grub config and probably the initrd to reflect that, otherwise chances are the system won't boot!

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to have to digest this as I feel I could become seriously unstuck!

Comment: Be sure to have good backups. And major partition change may damage system. Better to start over and use gpt partitioning as recommended with UEFI and required with Windows in UEFI. Ubuntu does let you use the very old MBR(msdos) partitioning with uefi but really should not. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR Note change from MBR to gpt will totally erase drive, so backups required (and not image backup as MBR cannot be restored to gpt)

Comment: The filesystem UUID won't change by moving around partitions.

Answer (score 1):

You can never extend partitions to the left. You can only copy their contents left, then extend to right.

## First: make a backup of your data

No backup is not an option.

## Either

You can copy the contents of the EFI partition to a new primary partition at
the very beginning of your disk. EFI doesn't care about where exactly that partition starts, just that it exists and is FAT formatted. (EFI is *much* nicer than BIOS!)

Then you can delete the original EFI partition.

Using a bootable live linux stick,

- add a new ext4 partition after the new ESP partition
- copy the files from your existing ext4 `/` partition over there (`sudo cp -ar` )
- delete the old ext4 partition
- extend the size of the new ext4 partition
- bind-mount `/proc`, `/dev`, `/sys` into the mount of the new partition,
- mount the new ESP partition as `/boot/EFI` inside the mount of the new partition
- `chroot` into it, and

  - modify the `/etc/fstab` of your target system to mount the right `/` partition
  - regenerate the initrd images from there (how to do that depends on your linux distro)
  - regenerate the Grub config (how to do that depends on your linux distro)

## Or

Or, and probably preferable, but requires that your Linux distro does that without changes to the boot loader, instead of all these different partitions, leave the ESP partition as is.

- Add a new partition in the empty space
- use `pvcreate` to make it an LVM physical volume (PV)
- make a new volume group (`vgcreate`) that contains that PV
- make a new logical volume the size of your current ext4 `/` partition in that volume group (`vgcreate`)
- format that volume as ext4
- copy over the file contents of your old `/`, fix the /etc/fstab and the initrds as described above
- Try whether you can boot and it now boots using the new volume, instead of the old (**this is your safe point of return**)
- delete the old ext4 partition
- add a new PV that uses all the disk's now free space
- add the new PV to the volume group (`vgextend`)
- you can (if you want to) now extend the size of the logical volume (`lvresize -r`), but you can also do that later on, during usage, with no downside.

Comment: Hmm - much more complicated and scarier than I thought it would be (perhaps the replies should be prefaced with 'Here be Tygers'!)

Comment: yeah… sorry about that! I wish Linux installers would always default to installing on LVM or some other volume manager instead of doing something that always ends up complicating things, namely installing on native partitions. (If your system was already LVM, then the instructions would have been three steps: 1. make a new PV on the free space, 2. add the PV to the existing volume group, 3. resize the logical volume that you want to resize)

Comment: Many thanks for the comprehensive reply Marcus. I have done a little bit of basic partition manipulation in the past, but nothing as complex (and potentially hazardous) as this. I'll let the information seep into my brain a bit, but it's not so easy at 84 years old!

Comment: Keep it simple @JimFord but use the GPT partitioning scheme next time.